# Meteorjs aggregate in publications

Tags: meteor

For this collection:

```
{
    room: 'room1',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time1'
},

{
    room: 'room1',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time2'
},

{
    room: 'room2',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time3'
},

{
    room: 'room2',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time4'
},

{
    room: 'room3',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time5'
},

{
    room: 'room3',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time6'
}
```

How can publish data so that it returns the document with greatest time for each **room**:

```
{
    room: 'room1',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time2'
},

{
    room: 'room2',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time4'
},

{
    room: 'room3',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time6'
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried any aggregation?

Comment: I know mongodb aggregation but I do not know how to use them in meteorjs? Is it possible something like Collection.aggregate()?

Comment: With a package, https://atmospherejs.com/?q=aggregat